# Is there a "John Carter" (2012) script with the actors' lines in Barsoomian?

Tags: john-carter

It would be a great novelty to have Paul Frommer's Barsoomian dialogue in and of itself, but I'm doing some conlang research and a transliteration would be handy, especially where some lines are spoken simultaneously.

Comment: http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/JohnCarterofMars.pdf - It appears to be total gibberish

Comment: No, Paul Frommer of "Avatar" fame constructed a bit of dialogue with syntax, grammar, etc. Also, your link is not the script, but appears to be screenplay set in present day, so whatever's in it may be gibberish, but also moot.

Comment: Sure, but this screenplay looks like gibberish

Comment: Perhaps why it didn't get made.

Comment: Yes, can you imagine what would have happened if they'd made this version. It could have been a total flop and critically panned.

Comment: For Helium's sake, @Valorum, are you a Thark to show so little mercy?